# Ошибка 2452. выражение содержит недопустимую ссылку на свойство Parent

Tags: access

**Используется**
Accecc - 2016

Имеются подчинённые формы:
- 001_001_Запрос1;
- 02_подчиненная форма tst_004_car;
- 03_подчиненная форма tst_005_zpch;

При открытии подчинённых форм появляется ошибка:
- 2452. введённое выражение содержит недопустимую ссылку на свойство Parent

**Вопрос.**
1. Как исправить ошибку?
2. Как выявить это выражение?

**[ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/zyeo7) на файл**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы открываете подчиненную форму напрямую, когда у нее нет родительской формы. Если вы откроете главную форму Form1, то подчиненная форма в качестве субформы будет работать, как и планировалось. Если вы все-же хотите открывать подчиненную форму напрямую (что не есть правильно), то перед выполнением кода для родительской формы нужна проверка, является ли форма подчиненной или свободной.

А выявить, где ошибка очень просто - нажмите на кнопку Debug, редактор кода покажет линию с ошибкой.